# Parse JSON/YAML file from C# Winform application

Tags: c#, json, winforms, yaml

I am having one yaml file with several endpoints. How to parse YAML/JSON file programmatically in C#, with corresponding Parameters, Body, Response etc.

example,
If that file contains a post endpoint and Request body as shown below,

```
requestBody:
   content:
       application/json; charset=utf-8:
       schema:
            $ref: "#/components/schemas/CreateSample"
   
CreateSample:
      title: Sample
      description: The input data for the create sample.
      type: object
      properties:
        sampleValue:
          description: Test
          type: string
          maxLength: 80
        sampleId:
          description: Test ID.
          maxLength: 1000
          type: string
```

I have to get the body param in string  as shown below.

```
{
  "sampleValue": "string",
  "sampleId": "string"
}
```

Comment: The fact that this is in Windows Forms seems somewhat irrelevant. There are various JSON libraries and various YAML libraries - have you tried using any of them yet?

Comment: I tried with newtonsoft, but how to get as above format. This is for a window appliation, reading the file and can run like postman.

Comment: "This is for a window appliation" - but again, how do you expect that to change the code? If you say you've tried with Newtonsoft.Json, please show what you've tried and what happened compared with what you want. Are you having trouble parsing the file, or creating the JSON? Those are two potentially very separate tasks.

Comment: I tried to read YAML using following code :  var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder().WithNamingConvention(UnderscoredNamingConvention.Instance)  
    .Build();
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(endPoint))
                        {
                           var  dex = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
                            
                            foreach(var item in (Dictionary<object,object>)dex)
                            {
                                if(item.Key.ToString() == "paths")
                                {

Comment: But it will get as an object only, so is there is any option that will return json string if $ref is there also.

Comment: All of that information should be in the question. You still haven't told us which YAML library you're using, but with YamlDotNet you can effective transcode YAML to JSON using `new SerializerBuilder().JsonCompatible().Build();` - just serialize `dex` to a `StringWriter`, and you'll get JSON.